# Xcode apparently does not create the app’s dSYM file

Tags: ios, xcode, dsym, symbolicate

I am developing an iOS app. Sometimes when I execute the development version on a test device that is **not** connected to Xcode, the app crashes.
I later connect it to Xcode and display the device logs, and can see the crash log.

Unfortunately, my Xcode Version 12.5 (12E262) does not symbolicate my app. Apparently, Xcode does not find the required dSYM file, although I have set in Targets/Build Settings "Debug Information Format" to "DWARF with dSYM file".

I have read the docs „Adding Identifiable Symbol Names to a Crash Report“, particularly the section [Locate a dSYM Using Spotlight](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding-identifiable-symbol-names-to-a-crash-report#Locate-a-dSYM-Using-Spotlight). Accordingly:
In the „Binary Images:“ part of my crash report, my app is shown:

```
0x104c30000 - 0x104dd3fff ShopEasy arm64  <2f9607e3500937bdb7f84ad8f4c103d5> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/8CC841E3-385A-4779-97AF-1399E4D108F5/ShopEasy.app/ShopEasy
```

However, if I open `var` in the Finder, the folder `containers` is empty.

When I search in Terminal for the UUID using

```
mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == 8CC841E3-385A-4779-97AF-1399E4D108F5"
```

it does not find anything.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Did you set the Debug Information Format build setting to DWARF with dSYM File for the Debug build configuration? Initially Xcode is set to create dSYM files for the Release build configuration but not the Debug build configuration so a development version of an app will not have a dSYM file.

Comment: Yes, the Debug Information Format is set to DWARF with dSYM File for all build configurations.

Comment: One of the great unsolved mysteries. What I've observed is that the Build folder often doesn't contain the dSYM file until some minutes later. And on subsequent new builds the dSYM file isn't always updated, so Instruments (or other things needing the dSYM) are left with outdated and unusable dSYMs. This seems to surely be an Xcode bug, but it's been going on more than a decade? What's the deal, Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is really the solution:
In `Target / Build Settings`, `Debug Information Format` was set to `DWARF with dSYM File`.
I reset it to `DWARF` only, and then set it again to `DWARF with dSYM File`.
Now my crash logs are symbolicated.